# What controls the Skype availability display in Outlook?

Tags: skype, microsoft-outlook-2013

The other day, I installed Outlook 2013 at home and it started displaying avatars for my contacts and showing if they are online in Skype.

I did not install any add-in or change any settings in either program to get that functionality. At work, I also use Skype and Outlook 2013, but I don't get the same behavior.

What controls this behavior and how can I enable/disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is controlled solely by **Skype for Business for Outlook** add-on.

Source: [blog on TechNet.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/samdrey/2016/08/15/skype-for-business-and-outlook-presence-information-on-outlook-how-to-get-it-answer-here/)

To see presence lights in Outlook:

> You must install the ***Skype for Business for Outlook*** add-on, and the user with which you’re logged in on Outlook must have the Skype SIP address in his list of E-Mail addresses.

Answer (score 1):

In Outlook you have option to show online status and photographs.

Go to `--> File --> Options`. New window will open. Click on `Contacts` on the left hand side. To disable "Online Presence Indicator" un-tick `Display online status next to name`. If you want to enable it - just tick that box. You can do the same for photos but that would require Outlook restart.

Comment: That option is checked and greyed out in my client at work, but I don't get the indicator here.

Comment: I've tested it and it works for me.